# JSON parse throws JSON exception in android

Tags: android, json, parsing, reddit

I am trying to parse a JSON document in Android and I have previously been able to do so using the same logic. But in this section of the website my code seems to break and I've been spending hours trying to compare what changed but I cant tell. What am I missing here?

Can someone educate me on why my attempt failed?

**The target JSON**

```
[ { "data" : { "after" : null,
    "before" : null,
    "children" : [ { "data" : { "approved_by" : null,
              "author" : "BuzzAldrinHere",
              "author_flair_css_class" : null,
              "author_flair_text" : null,
              "banned_by" : null,
              "clicked" : false,
              "created" : 1404871393.0,
              "created_utc" : 1404842593.0,
              "distinguished" : null,
              "domain" : "self.IAmA",
              "downs" : 0,
              "edited" : 1404849572.0,
              "gilded" : 0,
              "hidden" : false,
              "id" : "2a5vg8",
              "is_self" : true,
              "likes" : null,
              "link_flair_css_class" : "science",
              "link_flair_text" : "",
              "media" : null,
              "media_embed" : {  },
              "name" : "t3_2a5vg8",
              "num_comments" : 7331,
              "num_reports" : null,
              "over_18" : false,
              "permalink" : "/r/IAmA/comments/2a5vg8/i_am_buzz_aldrin_engineer_american_astronaut_and/",
              "saved" : false,
              "score" : 4968,
              "secure_media" : null,
              "secure_media_embed" : {  },
              "selftext" : "I am hopi...
```

**The Code attempt**

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray hotTopics = data.getJSONArray("children");
        for(int i=0; i<hotTopics.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject topic = hotTopics.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("data");
            DetailsData item = new DetailsData();
            item.setAuthor(topic.getString("author"));

            item.setPostTime(topic.getLong("created_utc"));
            item.setScore(topic.getString("score"));
            item.setComment(topic.getString("selftext"));
```

**Seemingly Identical JSON that it actually worked for**

```
{ "data" : { "after" : "t3_2a8ij0",
  "before" : null,
  "children" : [ { "data" : { "approved_by" : null,
            "author" : "JiveMonkey",
            "author_flair_css_class" : null,
            "author_flair_text" : null,
            "banned_by" : null,
            "clicked" : false,
            "created" : 1404948237.0,
            "created_utc" : 1404919437.0,
            "distinguished" : null,
            "domain" : "i.imgur.com",
            "downs" : 0,
            "edited" : false,
            "gilded" : 0,
            "hidden" : false,
            "id" : "2a8tuu",
            "is_self" : false,
            "likes" : null,
            "link_flair_css_class" : null,
            "link_flair_text" : null,
            "media" : null,
            "media_embed" : {  },
            "name" : "t3_2a8tuu",
            "num_comments" : 1932,
            "num_reports" : null,
            "over_18" : false,
            "permalink" : "/r/pics/comments/2a8tuu/norway_has_invented_a_bicycle_escalator/",
            "saved" : false,
            "score" : 4894,
            "secure_media" : null,
            "secure_media_embed" : {  },
            "selftext" : "",
            "selftext_html" : null,
            "stickied" : false,
            "subreddit" : "pics",
            "subreddit_id" : "t5_2qh0u",
            "thumbnail" : "http://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/nIstmQ8l1jl-UiU8.jpg",
            "title" : "Norway has invented a bicycle escalator",
            "ups" : 4894,
            "url" : "http://i.imgur.com/ACr2e4h.jpg",
            "visited" : false
          },
        "kind" : "t3"
      },
```

Comment: The "selfText" item data is broken in the `target JSON` section (at least what you have posted).

Comment: sorry that was a typo, i had it right in my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target JSON is a `JSONArray`, where as the "seemingly identical" JSON is a `JSONObject`

I Imagine if you looked at the Stack Trace for the thrown `JSONException`, It would tell you that `JSONArray` cannot be parsed as a `JSONObject`

To parse it you could change the code to the following:

```
JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject response = jArr.getJSONObject(0); // grab the first object in the array
```

Comment: Oh I see the extra bracket now, wow good catch. Do you have a suggestion about how to adjust the code? Just change the JSONObject type to Array?

Comment: So you are saying change  JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray hotTopics = data.getJSONArray("children"); to your suggestion? This isn't quite working for me.. can you clarify?

Comment: I'm saying replace JSONOBject response = new JSONObject(result); with the code I have provided